# Apache not working after Windows 8.1 upgrade

Tags: php, mysql, apache, upgrade, windows-8.1

After upgrading to Windows 8.1 from Windows 8 today Apache isn't working anymore. I had this problem when upgrading last time to Windows 8 from Windows 7 and had to re-install all my server components but I don't want to do that this time as I loose all the databases I had before.

Does anyone know what I can do to reconnect my Apache server, PHP and MySQL servers?

Apache 2.2
PHP 5.

Comment: An OS upgrade is a big thing. Actually, it's a **HUGE** thing. If you're going to upgrade, you need to be aware of the costs and you should have backed up your databases.

Comment: Check your ports.  I had a problem with my Apache ports conflicting with the ports being installed with the bundled Skype.  I changed my ports to 8888 and worked great. Server problems can be frustrating.

Comment: I still have all the files there in my MySQL data folder, is there any way of getting the data out of them?

Comment: Do you have MySQL, Apache or WAMP services installed? Click `Windows + R` and type `services.msc`. Check the list of services, and start Apache, MySQL and WAMP services. It would be helpful if you you install each server one by one, or if you used a package.

Comment: @Kiewic I've installed them all separately. The services aren't running or show up in services.msc any more. I've tried re-installing the Apache service with httpd.exe -k install but it gives me "(OS5)Access is denied. : Failed to open WinNT service manager"

Comment: Did you run it from an elevated command prompt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should start the MySQL, Apache and/or WAMP services from `services.msc`. If cannot find them, you will need to re-install them as services.

In few words, you need to execute the following binaries from an elevated command prompt:

- `httpd.exe -k install`, here is how it works: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/platform/windows.html#winsvc
- `mysqld.exe --install`, here is how it works http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-start-service.html

If you cannot find them, try this from a command prompt:

```
cd c:\
dir /s /b mysqld.exe
dir /s /b httpd.exe
```

Then you will find them.

Comment: Just worked this out too. Need to run cmd as admin otherwise doesn't work. Thanks for your help