# How to install WAMP Apache Service on Windows 8.1

Tags: apache, wamp

I'm trying to run WAMP 64 bits on Windows 8.1 but it's not working ; When I launch it, the icon is orange and localhost isn't find.

I've completly uninstalled Skype, tried to modify httpd.conf, hosts file like said on topics, but nothing to do.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480443/apache-not-working-after-windows-8-1-upgrade) (`httpd.exe -k install`) but it throws me an error : `the application was unable to start correctly [...]`.

The other command works partially (doesn't throw an error).
I've downloaded and installed C++ Redistribuable but it doesn't affect WAMP apparently.

Any idea ?

EDIT : here are my MSVC runtimes installed :

```
2008 - x64 9.0.21022
2008 - x64 9.0.30729.6161
2008 - x86 9.0.30729
2008 - x86 9.0.30729.6161
2010 - x64 10.0.40219
2010 - x86 10.0.30319
2012 - x64 11.0.61030
2012 - x86 11.0.61030
```

EDIT2 : see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445238/wamp-server-not-working-on-8-1/20378496#20378496), the `wampapache` service is not shown (maybe not installed ?!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make sure you have all the correct MSVC runtimes installed

Please make sure you have the latest version of all of these Microsoft C++ Redistributable runtime libraries.

The 2008 Redist is used by wampmanager

The 2010 Redist is used by some versions of Apache/MySQL/PHP ( depending on compiler used )

The 2012 Redist is used by some versions of Apache/MySQL/PHP ( depending on compiler used )

***FOR WAMP 32bit***

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5582)

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=8328)

If you are using WampServer 2.4 or greater

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30679)  And select vcredist_x86.exe

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53840) And select vc_redist.x86.exe

***FOR WAMP 64bit***

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5582)

**Yes you need the x86 Package regardless**

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15336)

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13523)

If you are using WampServer 2.4 or greater

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30679) And select vcredist_x64.exe

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53840) And select vcredist_x64.exe and vc_redist.x86.exe

***Next***
Ensure you have a correctly configured `hosts` file

`C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` should contain

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
::1 localhost
```

**EDIT1**

If you dont think the Apache and MySQL services are installed

1. Check if you can see these 2 services `wampapache` and `wampmysql` if they are in your services lists they were installed.
2. If you want to reinstall them, just to be sure, do this:

   left click wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Remove Service
   left click wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Install Service

   left click wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Remove Service
   left click wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Install Service

If Apache still failes to start, view your `Event Log`, in the Applications section there may be messages from Apache and/ot MySQL. Apache will write errors here if they happen before it can open its error log, ditto for MySQL.

Comment: Thanks, I've installed all MSVC runtimes but it isn't working.  I still have the same error. I edited my post with all runtimes installed

Comment: Try installing the 32bit 2005 MSCV runtime, it is on my system and maybe WAMP needs that for wampmanager

Answer (score 1):

Had similar problem. For some reason they do not make sure that you have the latest vc++ redistributable in the installation

My missing part was:

Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145

Select 64 bit when you download.

Answer (score 0):

Fix all your problems regarding wamp server and port number by installing latest version of wamp server i.e, wampserver3 from here -
http://netix.dl.sourceforge.net/project/wampserver/WampServer%203/WampServer%203.0.0/wampserver3_x64_apache2.4.17_mysql5.7.9_php5.6.16_php7.0.0.exe

and then go to wamp->apache->use port other than 80 and select this.
Now, your wamp server is configured to work successfully !!