# wampserver 2.2 64x could not execute menu item (internal error)[Exception] Could not execute run action: the directory name is invalid

Tags: mysql, apache, wampserver, port80

Working with the Wampserver 2.2 64x on win8.1, suddenly it has stopped starting services.its giving the following error:

```
wampserver 2.2 64x could not execute menu item (internal error)[Exception] Could not execute run action: the directory name is invalid
```

What i have done yet is start all Services/Restart All Services and restart wampserver, didn't work!

I tried to Install Service:

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Install Service.
```

cmd saying `Actually Port 80 is used by server:Microsoft HTTPAPI/2.0`

But MySQL Install Service: wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Install Service. doesn't work!

And also i tried to change port 80 (httpd.conf)

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80
```

to

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 8080
```

after a restart of Wampserver its try icon got active(green) but still not working (giving the error)

Even i did System restore to the date where it was working with no errors but didn't work.

Any one know whats wrong with this?

Comment: Check out the [first result](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=microsoft%20httpapi/2.0) on **Google** when searching the server using port 80.

Answer (score 0):

This message from the `test port 80` function

```
Actually Port 80 is used by server:Microsoft HTTPAPI/2.0
```

is saying that you have recently installed or activated IIS or maybe SQLServer.

Because the IIS or SQLServer services are configured to Start Automatically after a boot they have already grabbed Port 80 so when you start Apache it cannot get hold of port 80.

So either uninstall IIS or SQLServer or change their startup type using the Services snapin to `Manual` or even `Disable` them and then reenable them when you want to use them.

Things I know can grab port 80 and are related to IIS and SQLServer installs are

1. IIS
2. Web Deploy
3. MS Sql Server Reporting service.
4. BranchCache ( Windows 8.1 )

There may be others

How to find out whats using port 80

From a command window, started using "Start as Administrator" do

```
netstat -anop TCP | find ":80"

TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4852
```

Look at the result of this command and then put the PID number ( last number on the line ) into this command

```
tasklist /FI "PID eq 4852" ?FO TABLE /NH
httpd.exe                     4852 Services                   0     19,720 K
```

In this example Apache is using port 80 but yours will probably be something different

Comment: Hi RiggsFolly, thanks for instructions, manually I couldn't assign port 80 to Apache, so I Uninstalled those apps:
1-IIS
2-Web Deploy
3-MS Sql Server Reporting service.
3-BranchCache ( Windows 8.1 )
which may be using port 80, after reboot Wampserver got working and services working properly (I CAN ACCESS LOCALHOST) from browser but  not (FROM TASKBAR TRY ICON) which gives the upper error, Well for the sack of my work the problem is solved.

Comment: Check you have all the required MSVC C/C++ runtime libraries. [See here for a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20429762/how-to-install-wamp-apache-service-on-windows-8-1_

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to fix this i found was
- i uninstalled chrome so this broke down
just manually write locahost in explorer and works again.