# why i have to give port number manually in the browser

Tags: php, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, wamp, wampserver

I have changed the port already in wamp but when I run wamp I got

> error 404-not found

All the time I have to give port number manually from 80 t0 81

> "http://localhost/phpmyadmin/" to "http://localhost:81/phpmyadmin/"

How to solve this problem.
I did not install skype.
I have installed vs2010,SqlServer2012

I have done following things with wamp--

> changed port from 80 to 81 in Apache=>httpd.conf file

Comment: IIS comes with other apps that also use port 80, here is a [post that may help you remove them all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492960/wampserver-2-2-64x-could-not-execute-menu-item-internal-errorexception-could/27500816#27500816) It is always best to get your web server running on port 80 if at all possible

Answer (score 1):

Because the convention with http protocol is that if no port is added, it will be 80.  If the port is 81, then without specifying the port, it will use 80 and your wamp won't be accessed.  Try using the port at 80 and accessing it with http://localhost:80/phpmyadmin.  You'll find that you can access it just the same as http://localhost/phpmyadmin.

Comment: but when i use port 80 my wamp sever did not starts. even i change iis http port

Comment: If it didn't start, it's possible something else is running on port 80 already.

Comment: can't wamp find port automatically?

Comment: @rahul Suppose the program detected automatically and switched to a new port.  What port might that be?  It isn't the type of thing you want handled automatically.  You can either leave wamp at 81 or you can figure out what is occupying port 80 and change it.  netstat -ano is an infinitely useful command for this type of thing.

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem by following

Open the wampmanager.tpl file. On my machine, it’s located here:   C:\wamp\wampmanager.tpl
Do a search for “http://localhost/” and replace it   with “http://localhost:81/” (There are four total).
Do a search for   “${w_testPort80}” and replace it with “${w_testPort81}”.
Save and close the   file.

now wamp automatically listening to port 81

thanks all

Comment: Move to WAMPServer 3 and there are menu items to change port number automatically and consistantly accross all files, so you would not have to fo this manually.